# How to get entire row when finding the max of a column in R

Tags: r

I have a data table called data that has a column for "Types of Business" and a column counting the number of times that type of business occurs.

So the table looks like

```
 Var1                  Freq
Food Drink              3
Insurance              10
Hotels                  0
Materials               1
Media                   4
```

I want to find the max of Freq and still return the Var1.
When I try max(data$Freq) it only returns the number 10. I want the return value to be

```
 Var1          Freq
Insurance       10
```

Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: `data[which.max(data$Freq),]`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

I also recommend using the package `dplyr` since it is much easier to read. To do this you would use the function `filter`

```
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(header = T, text = 
"Var1                  Freq
Food_Drink              3
Insurance              10
Hotels                  0
Materials               1
Media                   4"
) 

filter(df, Freq == max(Freq))
```